# asmx file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I am using http://api.jangomail.com/ api in my web application and added a reference using "Add service refernce" and giving the path http://api.jangomail.com/api.asmx and selecting the HttpGet in add service reference.

I want to use this method :

http://api.jangomail.com/help/html/655d20ca-2164-c483-fb21-d3d0ee049155.htm

But I dont get intellisense? Do I need to add assembly reference or what?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need to add any assembly.
You just need to reference to the [web service](http://api.jangomail.com/api.asmx) and, when asked, you have to give a proper name to the namespace. 
If the reference has been created you will see a "Service References" folder with your service object (let's say ServiceReference1) and the configuration files (wsdl, etc).

Now you can write your code:

```
        var jango = new ServiceReference1.JangoMailHttpGetClient();
        jango.SendTransactionalEmail();
```

Comment: I used the above code and I get this error:An endpoint configuration section for contract 'JangoMail.JangoMailSoap' could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.

Comment: @DotNetSparrow Take a look at your web.config. There should be 2 endpoints described. Delete one of them (or both if you don't know which and reference the service again)